# How to get XmlSchema object from XSD which is string in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, string, xsd

How to get XmlSchema object from large string that contains all XSD content?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx):

```
string content = ".......";
XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(new StringReader(content), ValidateSchema);
```

Comment: Exactly, just it will fail if content has include tag when you try validate xml with this schema, because you must first add all includes then the most parent xsd, which is not case when you use URI. Thanks.

Comment: @eomeroff How do you go about adding these includes? some code would be great :).

Comment: Instance od schema does not contains Read method

Answer (score 27):

The Read method is static. So better use

```
XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(
    schemaReader, (sender, args) =>
    {
         // HANDLE VALIDATION FAILED
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string xsdContent = "...";
string xmlContent = "...";

XmlSchemaSet schema;
XDocument xmlDoc;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xsdContent)))
{
    var xsc = XmlSchema.Read(ms, (o, e) =>
    {
        Error.SetWarning($"XML Schema error: {e.Message}");
    });
    schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schema.Add(xsc);
    xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
}

xmlDoc.Validate(schema, (o, e) =>
{
    // handle validation errors
});
```